# Cursor which create user and assign role

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have list of users which all will requer to be on server which used domain autentification, I have temp table in which Ian loading my users from cab file.
Than I need to create users based on records in my temp file

How to do cursor to create this records?

I was trying to do

```
DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR
FOR
SELECT *
FROM #temp;

OPEN cursor1

FETCH NEXT
FROM cursor1
INTO @userprofile

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
    CREATE user @userprofile
    FOR LOGIN @userprofile GO

    EXEC sp_addrolemember 'role'
        ,@userprofile

    FETCH NEXT
    FROM cursor1
    INTO @userprofile
END

CLOSE cursor1

DEALLOCATE cursor1
```

However it's throwing me an error

```
Msg 102 Incorrect syntax near @userprofile and msg 137 must declare the scalar variable @userprofile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use variables inline as object names with the calls to commands such as CREATE USER. You need to do something like this and use dynamic sql instead:

**EDIT** - You could also use sp_adduser instead of dynamic sql in this example. However, this stored procedure has been deprecated as of SQL Server 2012. Therefore, if you are using this version of above, stick with dynamic sql and the CREATE USER command.

**Dynamic SQL if SQL2012 or greater**

```
DECLARE @UserProfile VARCHAR(20)

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR
    FOR
        SELECT
            *
        FROM #temp;
OPEN cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @UserProfile
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Sql = 'Create user ' + @UserProfile + ' for login ' + @UserProfile

    --PRINT @SQL
    EXEC (@Sql)

    EXEC sp_addrolemember   'role'
                            ,@UserProfile

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @UserProfile
END
CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
```

**sp_adduser if prior:**

```
EXEC sys.sp_adduser @LogInAme = @UserProfile
                        ,@Name_In_Db = @UserProfile
```

I have commented out the PRINT statement. However, if you uncomment it. You can see the commands it's creating from the cursor.

Comment: I tried two examples it still throwing me same error

Comment: The exact same error message? I've noticed an edit to your original post no longer contains this line at the top 'DECLARE @UserProfile VARCHAR(20)'. Is that still in your query?